# Trigger on Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to return different results to user when using Select because it returns wrong value and i cant use view or something else because its third party appliction.

I want to make instead of his select perform another select trigger or any thing else.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server doesn't have the concept of a `INSTEAD OF SELECT` (nor an `AFTER SELECT`) trigger - you will need to find another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually SQl server Supports [Trigger on an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), there is no concept of [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164047.aspx) on Select statement.
You can write stored procedure to implement you logic or you have to find some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my proposed solution in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9390810/1225214).

> "Use a VIEW and INSTEAD OF triggers to make it behave as a table and
>   you can accomplish the equivalent of an INSTEAD OF SELECT trigger
>   among other interesting things...."