# Catch conditional parameters in SQL Server select trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to know that, when I write a select trigger (instead of select), how catch conditional parameters in this trigger?

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Triggers are triggered by update, insert and delete statements. Not for select.

Comment: As others have said, there's no such thing as a "select trigger", and to add to that, triggers don't have parameters. Perhaps you can put a sample of what you've written so far, so we can see what you're actually talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can write an "INSTEAD OF SELECT" trigger. It sounds like a view or table-valued function to me.

Comment: You can read like "if I write a select trigger; how can I catch conditional parameters in this?

Comment: @bedreddin: there **is no such thing** as a SELECT trigger...... neither `BEFORE SELECT`, nor `AFTER SELECT`, nor `INSTEAD OF SELECT`

Comment: Oh.. I have to trig when table select.. How do I do?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish. There are many potential answers (stored procedures, table-valued functions, SQL Profiler traces), any of which could fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Use a VIEW and `INSTEAD OF` triggers to make it behave like a table and you can accomplish the equivalent of an `INSTEAD OF SELECT` trigger among other interesting things.

I wrote a very simple explanation at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/sqldatabaseengine/thread/1cd57540-b5c1-459f-accb-480d2ac2b501

Search the page for "Michael_R. _"